# QThread communicate threadsafe

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I know it's not allowed to call a function of another thread in Mainthread. Is it allowed to call a signal form another thread without any problems? Lets say this code is in MainWindow:

thread->moveTOThread(obj);
emit obj->Signal();

thank you

---

or is this the way to go:

```
 Obj.h
signals:
    void testSignal(); 
public slots:
void Func();

    MainWindow.h
    void testSignal(); 

    MainWindow.cpp
    thread->moveTOThread(obj); 
    connect(this,SIGNAL(testSignal()),obj,SIGNAL(testSignal()));
    emit testSignal(); 

    Obj.cpp
    connect(this,SIGNA(testSignal()),this,SLOT(Func()));
```

Answer (score 5):

**Yes!** A signal can be called from any thread as long as you use the default automatic connection to the signal. Such slots/functors will execute in their context object's thread. You can emit signals from callbacks from 3rd party libraries, for example, even if these libraries don't use Qt.

**Warning**: Any explicitly directly connected slots/functors will execute in the thread where the signal was invoked.

Comment: Do you know what is the approch to call a function from another thread? Why not just call the function from another threads object from main-gui-thread? I see no problem, if i only call functions from other threads from there?

Comment: @Bob If the functions you're calling are not thread-safe, you're facing undefined behavior. You might "see" no problem, but you might be silently formatting your hard drive.

Comment: Idk i dont get an answer. Can i call a function of another thread without my programm crashes? Why should i use Signal and Slots when its extra code.

Comment: @Bob You can also use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod), if signals and slots are too much work for you. If you call a function directly, it will run in the thread you call it from. Unless the function you're calling is made thread-safe, you're risking getting a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) among other things.

Answer (score 2):

`connect` takes a 5th argument which is the connecion type.
The default value, `AutoConnection`, will use the thread safe `QueuedConnection` connection type assuming the objects were in different threads when the connect call was made. If they are in the same thread when the connection is made it will use a non threadsafe `DirectConnection` type connection.

Thread safetly is achieved by queueing the slot call as an event calling it in the destination thread when control returns to the event loop.

Comment: When you use [`Qt::AutoConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), the check is made when the signal is emitted, not when the connection is made.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what would happen if you do this. However, you are still crossing/breaking the thread boundary - and probably the signal will be emitted from the thread that you are calling emit in.

I believe a better approach is to connect a signal in your "calling" object to the signal in your "target" object. But even this is a bit bad in that the signal gets emitted immediately (maybe this is your intent), which is similar to a direct connection signal - which across threads, in my opinion, is very bad unless you have a very good reason (I can think of none).

But why not just connect a signal to a slot in your object which then emits your signal. This way you keep your thread boundary?

It seems like you are trying to force a signal in a different thread to run immediately... what is your use-case?

Comment: I just want to call a function of the obj somehow. Since obj->Func(); is not threadsafe I am searching for a threadsafe way. I tought maybe emit signal from obj and connect that signal in the obj-constructor to the Slot Func(). How can I call the Func()  threadsafe ????

Comment: @Bob Assuming `Class B` is the object living in another thread, just connect a signal from `Class A` to a slot in `Class B`. You don't have to connect a signal from `Class B` to a slot in `Class B`, and then call this signal.

Comment: @Bob well... you can just call that function directly if you want, no one can stop you. But it breaks the thread boundary and is not safe to do so. To call your object function safely the mechanism is to send a signal... its like two lines of code extra! One line to connect, one line to emit the signal (oh yeah and you need to declare the signal)... that's it! then all this fuss goes away. Alternatively if this is some kind of "helper" function where you don't need the object to be instantiated you could make it a static function...  what is your use case? or what does your function do?